# Aws-cdk addEventsource failing

Tags: aws-cdk

On adding the eventSource to the lambda function, the deploy is no longer working.

```
   const lambda = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs');
   const eventSource = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-sources');
   const fn = new lambda.NodejsFunction(this, 'tableConfigDynamoStreams', {
      entry: 'lambda/info/info.js',
    });
    const streamEventSource = new eventSource.DynamoEventSource(this.dynamoStack.tableInventory.configTable, {
      batchSize: 1
   });
      
   fn.addEventSource(streamEventSource)
```

Where configTable in the stack is holding the dynamodb table generated already ( in another stack ).
Everything runs fine till the fn.addEventSource(streamEventSource) line of code is executed.

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [tableConfigDynamoStreamsDyn
amoDBEventSource....
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled stream on your dynamodb table `stream: StreamViewType.NEW_IMAGE`.

Below code worked for me, it is similar to your code.

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { StartingPosition } from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';
import { AttributeType, BillingMode, StreamViewType, Table } from '@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb';
import { DynamoEventSource } from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-sources';
import { Construct, Stack } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { NodejsFunction } from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs';

export class CdkDemoStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, readonly dynamoStack: DynamoStack, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const demoFn = new NodejsFunction(this, 'DemoFunction', {
      entry: 'lambda/index.js'
    });
    const streamEventSource = new DynamoEventSource(this.dynamoStack.configTable, {
      batchSize: 1,
      startingPosition: StartingPosition.TRIM_HORIZON
    });
    demoFn.addEventSource(streamEventSource);
  }
}
export class DynamoStack extends Stack {
  readonly configTable: Table;
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id)
    this.configTable = new Table(this, 'ConfigTable', {
      partitionKey: {
        name: 'id',
        type: AttributeType.STRING
      },
      stream: StreamViewType.NEW_IMAGE
    });
  }
}
```

My `bin/infra.ts` file is like below

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { CdkDemoStack, DynamoStack } from '../lib/cdk-demo-stack';

const app = new cdk.App();
const dynamoDbStack = new DynamoStack(app, 'DynamoStack')
new CdkDemoStack(app, 'CdkDemoStack', dynamoDbStack);
```

Note: I am using CDK version `1.92.0`.